# Ошибка при отправке файлов на сервер

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Имеется код

```
$image = $_FILES['img'];
    //echo (print_r($_FILES['img']));
    {
        if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'],'/../web/avatars/'))
            return 'success';
        else
            return 'failure';
    }
```

При попытке загрузить файл возвращается ошибка 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory&#039

Comment: /../web/avatars/ - вы уверене в таком пути?

Comment: я писал путь относительно php файла. моя ошибка в этом?

Comment: Вы написали не относительно файла, а относительно файловой системы. '/' означает корень системы, '..' означает на уровень выше. А на уровень выше корня ничего быть и не может. В общем, уберите '/' в начале пути

Comment: Теперь всё работает. большое спасибо